# Listview view update [Angular+ Nativescript]

Tags: angular, nativescript

Hi i am trying to create an accordian using listview.  I have multiple templates inside one listview. When I click one template its corresponding second template must display. The problem i am facing is that when I click the accordian the ther other template is not displaying unless I screen lock my phone and re open it.(i.e the view is not updating.)
I tried using rad listview. In radlistview there is no binding issue in android . But the radlistview is not at all displaying in ios unless i give a perticular height for the layout (which i cant specify due to the height changes according to the phone.) . It would be great if any one could help me with this. I am attaching a sample code with listview along with this.

In brief: is there any method to update the view while using listview(tried using change detection stratergy and ngzone). Or a method to work properly using radlistview in IOS.

link: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=q6mBXb

Answer (score 0):

Your list item's template will not be updated upon your data changes. You will have to force the list item to be updated with some native code, I personally prefer RadListView over simple ListView and here is an example

[Creating a collapsible list with NativeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370335/creating-a-collapsible-list-with-nativescript)

Comment: RadListview is fine and working exactly intented in android. But not in ios. In ios it doesnot display radlistview unless you specify height for the layout inside the ng-template, which is not feasible becasue my data varies and it also create issue when the device changes.

Comment: We don't have to set height explicitly if you check the example in above thread.