# expand listview with multiple item.description

Tags: nativescript

By referring to the example provide below:
[Creating a collapsible list with NativeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370335/creating-a-collapsible-list-with-nativescript)

May I know how to expand the listview with multiple description like the following design?

[Multiple description example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kahs3.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple description"? Can you provide a [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org) with what are you trying to achieve and explain what is failing?

Comment: I'm new to native script, i added the example screen shot that i wish to achieve. it may need to put the description to [] but how can i load in the html?

Comment: Got it ... take a look at the answer provided. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following the example that you provided in the other question, you need another label in the ng-template of the ListView and to bind it to your additional descriptions like this:

```
  ...
  <ng-template accordionItemTemplate let-item="item" let-parent="parentIndex" let-even="even" let-child="childIndex">
      <StackLayout>
          <Label [text]="item.description"></Label>
          <Label [text]="item.description2"></Label>
          <Label [text]="item.description3"></Label>
      </StackLayout>
  </ng-template>
  ...
```