# Collapsible list with NativeScript doesn't work good

Tags: angular, nativescript

I follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370335/creating-a-collapsible-list-with-nativescript) to create collapsible list with Nativescript.

I have this html code:

```
       <RadListView [items]="evgpsbyclientid0" [itemTemplateSelector]="templateSelector" class="list-group"
            (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)" >
            <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
                <GridLayout rows="auto,auto" columns="6*,*" class="add-dropdown" style="position:fixed">
                    <Label [text]="item.device_serial" class="list-group-item" col="0"></Label>
                    <Image src="~/assets/images/dropdown.png" width="30" height="30" col="1"></Image>
                </GridLayout>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template tkTemplateKey="expanded" let-item="item">
                <GridLayout rows="auto,auto" columns="80*,auto" class="add-dropdown" style="position:fixed">
                    <Label [text]="item.device_serial" class="list-group-item" col="0"></Label>
                    <Image row="0" col="1" src="~/assets/images/dropup.png" width="30" height="30"></Image>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label [text]='"Data: " + item.datetime_device' class="show-answer"></Label>
                        <hr>
                        <Label [text]='"Desc: " + item.alarmdesc' class="show-answer"></Label>
                        <hr>
                        <Label [text]='"Seriali: " + item.device_serial' class="show-answer"></Label>
                        <hr>
                        <Label [text]='"Data Acted: " + item.dtm_acted' class="show-answer"></Label>
                        <hr>
                    </StackLayout>
                </GridLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </RadListView>
```

and this code in typescript

```
 import { isAndroid } from "platform";
 import { ListViewEventData } from "nativescript-ui-listview";

 public ngOnInit() {
    this.eventsgps.mobile_eventgetbyclientidActed0().subscribe(
            evgpsbyclientid0 => {
                this.evgpsbyclientid0 = evgpsbyclientid0;
            }
        );
    }

    templateSelector(item: any, index: number, items: any): string {
        return item.expanded ? "expanded" : "default";
      }

    onItemTap(event: ListViewEventData) {
        const listView = event.object,
            rowIndex = event.index,
            dataItem = event.view.bindingContext;

        dataItem.expanded = !dataItem.expanded;
        if (isAndroid) {
            listView.androidListView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(rowIndex);
        }
      }
```

The problem is like in image.
So in first image I show  only [text]="item.device_serial" and in second image I want to show in bottom other details. In image, my details show behind the text.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrvHy.jpg)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZJrI.jpg)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be your layout, you have 2 rows defined in `GridLayout` but you have never assigned what should appear in in row index `1`. Therefore all components will overlap in row index `0`.

Also I'm unsure what is `hr` in your code, guessing it's your custom component.

**Update:**

The expanded template should be something like,

```
        <ng-template tkTemplateKey="expanded" let-item="item">
            <GridLayout rows="auto,auto" columns="80*,auto" class="add-dropdown" style="position:fixed">
                <Label [text]="item.device_serial" class="list-group-item" col="0"></Label>
                <Image row="0" col="1" src="~/assets/images/dropup.png" width="30" height="30"></Image>
                <StackLayout row="1">
                    <Label [text]='"Data: " + item.datetime_device' class="show-answer"></Label>
                    <hr>
                    <Label [text]='"Desc: " + item.alarmdesc' class="show-answer"></Label>
                    <hr>
                    <Label [text]='"Seriali: " + item.device_serial' class="show-answer"></Label>
                    <hr>
                    <Label [text]='"Data Acted: " + item.dtm_acted' class="show-answer"></Label>
                    <hr>
                </StackLayout>
            </GridLayout>
        </ng-template>
```

Comment: Can you write something code please? I remove `row="0"` in `<Image .....></Image>` and `<hr>` but nothing change