# How to Expand only one item in collapsible list with NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, radlistview

I have built a RadListview with nativescript. But now I want that if I tap on an item then only that item should open and other Expanded items should close.
I followed this [Creating a collapsible list with NativeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370335/creating-a-collapsible-list-with-nativescript) and it works, I just need one  item expanding at a time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDRtx.png)

thank you

```js
export class RoadComponent {
    public roads: Array<any>;

    constructor(private page:Page,private router: Router, private roadService: RoadService,private back:BackendService) {
    }
  
    async ngOnInit() {
        this.roads = await this.roadService.getRoads();
    }
   
      templateSelector(item: any, index: number, items: any): string {
        return item.expanded ? "expanded" : "default";
      }
      
      onItemTap(event: ListViewEventData) {
        var listView = event.object as RadListView,
            rowIndex = event.index,
            dataItem = event.view.bindingContext;
            dataItem.expanded = !dataItem.expanded;           listView.androidListView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(rowIndex);

      }
      
      }
```

```html
<Page>
    <StackLayout>
            <RadListView multipleSelection="false" id="abc" height="100%" [items]="roads" [itemTemplateSelector]="templateSelector" class="list-group" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
              <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
              <StackLayout  id="abc" orientation="vertical">
             <Label text="{{item.name}}" class="list-group-item">
                </Label>       
             </StackLayout> 
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template   tkTemplateKey="expanded" let-item="item">
            <GridLayout  rows="auto,auto" columns="*,*" class="list-group-item add-dropdown">
              <Label   row="0" col="0" text="{{item.name}}" class="list-group-item"></Label>
              <Button  row="1" col="0" text="{{item.id}}" (tap)="navigatetomap(item.name)" [nsRouterLink]="['/accueil', { outlets: { homeoutlet: ['home'] } }]"></Button>
              <Button  row="1" col="1" text="{{item.name}}"></Button>
            </GridLayout>

        </ng-template>
        </RadListView>
      </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Comment: The original post you have linked already support expanding single item. If you have issues, please share a Playground example.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't, and I would show you my playground but I copied exactly what she did 
if I'm mistaken please tell me and thank you

Comment: I don't see the playground link anywhere, guess you missed it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here and still figuring out how to post. I added the playground now

Comment: Playground sample meaning you will have to go to https://play.nativescript.org/, add necessary code, save and post the link. It's more like a JS Fiddle, so others will be able to run the exact same code and debug.

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Yh22j6&_ga=2.121248520.1679795504.1557732551-264812028.1555594924&v=91                                                                                                          this is the playground of the tutorial that I followed, to save time because I did the same

Comment: It works as intended, did you mean you want to collapse other items when you expand one?

Comment: yes now I want that if I tap on an item then only that item should open and other Expanded items should close.

Comment: If you understand the logic here, it's pretty much simple. Upon tap, traverse through the list and collapse any existing item before expanding the one just tapped. Every time when you change the data attributes, you must call the native methods for those specific index to reload it.

Comment: i solve it like you said  , thank you                                                                                        
 for(let i=0;i<this.roads.length;i++){    
            this.roads[i].expanded=false;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone had this issue just make expanded property false to all the items

```
onItemTap(event: ListViewEventData) {
    for(let i=0;i<this.roads.length;i++){    
        this.roads[i].expanded=false;
    }
    var listView = event.object as RadListView,
        rowIndex = event.index,
        dataItem = event.view.bindingContext;
        dataItem.expanded = !dataItem.expanded;
       listView.androidListView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(rowIndex);

  }
```